# Do I need to keep the original page when 301 redirecting to a new one?

Tags: redirect

I've been editing a few pages including the URLs. Should I have kept these pages and made a new one and then redirected, or is it fine to just redirect a page that doesn't exist anymore?.

Thanks, 
Andy.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to keep the page when redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect old URL to new using 301 status code, all request to old URL will be redirected to new URL, also your server will send 301 status code, moved permanently.

You can delete old pages, because nothing will be able to access them anyway, as long as 301 redirection is active.

Comment: Many thanks Advanced SEO. Will the new page benefit from the old pages SEO if its redirected?

Comment: Yes, 301 redirection should pass (all, or, as much as possible) link quality from old page to new page. 301 status "Moved Permanently" is recommended for SEO. Please, do not forget to accept my answer if useful.